# Sending messages from C server to Java client

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send an array of string (`char ** topics`) from a C server to a Java client. Apparently, the server sends the topics properly, but the client does not receive them.

```
/* SERVER */
while (*topics != NULL) {
    printf("  > Sending topic '%s'.. ", *topics);
    if(write(sd, *topics, sizeof(*topics)) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[OK]\n");

    topics++;
}
```

The client looks like this:

```
/* CLIENT */
static void server_connection() {
        String topic = null;

        try {
            Socket _sd = new Socket(_server, _port); // Socket Descriptor

            // Create input stream
            DataInputStream _in = new DataInputStream(_sd.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader _br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_in));

            System.out.println("s> Current Topics:");

            while ((topic = _br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(topic);
            }

            if(topic == null) {
                System.out.println("Not topics found");
            }



            // Close socket connection
            _out.close();
            _in.close();
            _sd.close();

        } catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error in the connection to the broker " + _server + ":" + _port);
    }
  }
```

The client shows

```
s> Current Topics:
```

and remains waiting... :/

Comment: You might want to read about the `sizeof` operator in C.

Comment: Is the C server sending a newline character over the stream?  That is what `readLine` is blocking on in Java.

Comment: I've tried to concatenate "\n" to the end of the topic, but it's still the same

Comment: Wireshark......................

Comment: "*the server sends the topics properly*" how did you verify this?

Comment: Add a final `write(sd, '\n', 1);` and get enlightened.

Comment: Thanks  alk, that worked :)

Comment: Welcome. BTW, have you tested the sending code with "strings" longer than eight `char`s?

Answer (score 2):

```
write(sd, *topics, sizeof (*topics))
```

1. `topics` is a `char**`, so `*topics` is a pointer to `char`. `sizeof *topics` is therefore the size of that pointer, either 2 or 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture. This is not what you want. You want `strlen(*topics)`, assuming these are null-terminated strings.
2. As you're reading lines in the receiver, you need to send lines in the sender. Unless the data already contains a newline,, you need to add one in the sender.